# Downloader Middleware, Requests, and Responses

Tags: scrapy

I know that Middleware passes requests to the Downloader and responses to the Spider, but nothing explains what Downloader Middleware should be used to do and I cannot find a decent explanation anywhere.

What is its purpose? What are some of the ways that Downloader Middleware is used to modify requests and responses? Is the Downloader Middleware used to handle exceptions, manage proxies and user-agent strings, et cetera?

Answer (score 4):

Lets take an example given in scrapy's docs

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
            }
```

Well it works fine, but as you already know that it is not true for all the websites, like amazon.com

You need to send the user agent like (Mozilla's or Chrome's) in the request header and that way it knows that the request is coming from browser. you can easily change it from the settings by replacing USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36".

Now you have changed the user agent and the amazon's sever will feel like the request is coming from chrome browser. One step further you're increasing the concurrency to some large number like 100. Now what happens is amazon can easily track your bot and you'll get ban because what does that means is a single device is accessing the server 100 times in a second, which is not possible by human.

So here proxy rotation and user agent rotation comes in. The question is how we rotate them.

Lets say you have bunch of USER_AGENTS = [...] in your setting

*middlewares.py*
from .settings import USER_AGENT_LIST
import random
from scrapy import log

```
class UserAgentRotationMiddleware(object):
 
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        agent  = random.choice(USER_AGENT_LIST)
        if agent:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', agent)
```

And you have to tell the scrapy project like,

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   "yourproject.middlewares.UserAgentRotationMiddleware": 500
}
```

**What actually happens when you run the spider?**

Explanation:

1. Scrapy schedules request.
2. URL comes to the downloader middleware before request reaches to the server

Technically it will call the downloader middleware class, It calls process_request method with providing current **request object and spider object**

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
```

Now the request object is available to you, you can do any thing with it, like changing the headers proxy even url itself. but we are focused in user agent now.

so by our algorithm we will change the user agent,

```
# Choosing random user agent from a list
agent  = random.choice(USER_AGENT_LIST)
    if agent:
        request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', agent)
```

Again new request gets schedule comes to this middleware it'll change the user agent and it will pass the request object forward.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   "yourproject.middlewares.UserAgentRotationMiddleware": 500
}
```

While registering our project we have to specify some number between 100 to 900,
**what 500 it indicates?** (as value of middleware namespace)

There are number of different middlewares already exists in scrapy and also we can define many as we want now in such case
how can prioritise them?
what would be the order of execution of them?

It gets executed in ascending order like, 100, 200, 230, 500, 650, 900.

Same methodology applied for the proxy rotation.

**Request:**

If you have used lower level urllib or requests module, what it does?
It takes url as an argument (cookies, proxies, headers, payload optional arguments)

When you run it, what it does is?
It makes http request to the url "http://quotes.toscrape.com"

Like you normally would in browser:

1. Open up your browser.
2. Enter "http://quotes.toscrape.com" in url bar
3. Your browser shows that website

But there is lot goes on, between step 2 and 3.
Your browser takes an url requests to the server by using lower level http request. takes response then compiles it down and displays it in the browser.

The pseudo code which does the same thing,

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://quotes.toscrape.com')

print response.status_code
print response.content
```

requests.get to the url "http://quotes.toscrape.com"
send the HTTP GET request to "http://quotes.toscrape.com" which returns you the response. you can execute it and check it out it'll return some html to us **which is nothing but a response**.

What scrapy is doing to just provide their functionality it wraps you this requests module in scrapy.Request and response module to HttpResponse.

HttpResponse offers xpath & css selector.

```
def parse(self, response):
    response.xpath('....')
```

the response here provided by the scrapy framework in this parse method is an instance of HttpResponse which is a wrapper of lower level urllib's response object.

Comment: Much of that I'm already aware of since it's in the documentation. Perhaps I'm to blame since the title of my question is somewhat vague. The questions I've laid out at the bottom of my question are: **`"What is the purpose of a Downloader Middleware? What are some of the ways that Downloader Middleware is used to modify requests and responses? Is the Downloader Middleware used to handle exceptions, manage proxies and user-agent strings, et cetera?"`** You did answer some of these questions with the part of your answer regarding user-agent strings and proxies. Appreciate the effort nonetheless

Comment: If you could expound/elaborate/further explain those parts/topics, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @Anthony I can show you the example how I've used it for my benefit if you're interested in.

Comment: sure!! let's see your downloader middlewares!